# Creating a new project with Laravel throws an exception

Tags: laravel

I have installed Composer, Laravel, and PHP 7.1.22 with all extensions.

Now I try to create a new project using "laravel new projectname". It throws the exception below. How can I fix this problem?

> [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException]
>     cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 1080: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: Have you tried running composer install?

Comment: Please try the other way: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname`

Comment: @Rob i think composer install runs after project was created.

Comment: Oh! I thought your project is already created.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the `laravel` command fail you can try with `composer create-project`:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectname
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to remove ";" in extensions before the curl extension in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: he wrote that installed all extensions

Answer (score 3):

Try to run this:

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

Comment: yes i did run composer global require laravel/installer

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, check your firewall. Maybe it's blocking port 1080.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue when I copied the `laravel` directory from another machine instead of installing it via `composer global require laravel/installer`.

Try installing it if you copied.